# I need some solution please

Tags: warnings, environment, ns2, ns-3

I am getting the following error message:

```
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, using built in type maps.
Warning: Environment variable SUMO_HOME is not set, schema resolution will use slow website lookups.
Error: unable to open file 'https://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/types_file.xsd'
 In file 'built in type map'
 At line/column 1/0.

  The types could not be loaded from 'built in type map'.
Quitting (on error).
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the commands causing the warnings and the error message.

Answer (score 2):

> Error: unable to open file 'https://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/types_file.xsd'

It's http , not http**s**. ... Please see this site  https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/PlainXML → `$ wget http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/types_file.xsd`

My test  (I created a test dir. `sumo/TEST_COMMANDS/` with some default files + the "wget downloaded" `types_file.xsd`):

```
$ cd sumo/ && export SUMO_HOME="$PWD" && cd TEST_COMMANDS/

$ netconvert --node-files=input_nodes.nod.xml --edge-files=input_edges.edg.xml \
  --connection-files=input_connections.con.xml --type-files=types_file.xsd \
  --output-file=MySUMONet.net.xml
```

The terminal reply is : *Success.* ..... And the file `MySUMONet.net.xml` 61.4kB is created.